# How to create *.docx files from a template in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, docx

I have a working ASP.NET MVC web application to manage projects and customers. Now I want to generate a word file for some customers. In this file should be displayed some data about the customer. Every generated file should have the same data and the same design. So I want to craete a new Word Template with the fields and want to fill the placeholders programmatically.

My problem is that I couldn't find a clear way to do that. Does anybody know a good learning resources?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this page:

[Building Office Open XML Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163478.aspx)

Open XML files (docx) are ZIP packages containing XML files. In your case, I would create a copy of your original template, then use the `System.IO.Packaging` API to open the file and modify it. By opening, the correct XML file and replacing certain placeholders in XML, you should be able to achieve the result you want.

Comment: This is the way, or rather the link referenced is the way - you really don't want to "automate" (programatically control) word at all - this gives you an elegant separation between the template and the data too. The key terms in the article are "XML data store" and "content controls"

Answer (score 5):

While trying to do the same I have found some libraries to create/edit DOC or DOCX in .Net

- [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview)
- [TemplateEngine.Docx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TemplateEngine.Docx)
- [DocXTemplateEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/swxben.docxtemplateengine)
- [Templater](http://templater.info/) - [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Templater)
- [Spire.Doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html) - [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.Doc/)

Answer (score 0):

for the new document generation from a template file (.dot) should be very easy, I think it's a parameter you specify in the word application file open or so, when you pass the path of the .dot file, telling word to create a new .doc based on that file and not edit the actual template document.

for form fields and bookmarks filling, lots of examples online on how to do it from C#, see here:

[MS Word Office Automation - Filling Text Form Fields And Check Box Form Fields And Mail Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371093/ms-word-office-automation-filling-text-form-fields-and-check-box-form-fields-an)